# NP-hard: an instance or a set?

Tags: complexity-theory

When we say a problem is NP-hard is that a property of a set of problems or is it a property of a instance of the set of problems?

Comment: Rigorously, there is no such thing as "a problem is NP-Hard". A "set" $A$ is NP-Hard iff all sets in $NP$ are Karp-Reducible to $A$.  NP-Hardness is a property of a "set".

Comment: @swarnim_narayan No. A problem is just the membership question for one of these sets. Any problem is directly equivalent to the set of its yes-instances. For example, the 3-colourability problem is directly equivalent to the membership question, "Is $G$ a member of the set of 3-colourable graphs?"

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about terminology. You start correctly: "a problem is NP-hard". This already answers your question: hardness is a property of problems, not sets of problems or of instances.

To refresh, a problem is a question of the form, "Does the input object have this interesting property?" An instance is a specific object you're asking about.  So, for example, 3-colourability is the problem, "Can the vertices of the input graph be coloured red, green and blue such that there is no edge between vertices of the same colour?"  When you ask that question of a specific graph $G$, then $G$ is the instance.  (And a set of problems is just a set of problems: you know what a set is and you know what a problem is.)

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain how can we separate a problem from the set of problem? I don't get it. 3-SAT is a for me a set of problems and it has many instances in the set.